# Solving the equation $xax=b$ in a C*-algebra.

Tags: matrices, c-star-algebras, linear-algebra

Let $a, b\in A_+$ be positive elements of some *C**-algebra $A$.
Assume furthermore that $a$ is invertible.
Is it true that
$$
\exists! x\in A_+\quad:\quad xax=b\quad ?
$$

Already in the case $A=M_2(\mathbb C)$, I don't know how to solve this.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I do not know about general C<sup>*</sup>-algebras, but the statement is true for complex matrices.

**Uniqueness:** Assume *b* = *x**a**x*.  Then *a*<sup>1/2</sup>*b**a*<sup>1/2</sup> = *a*<sup>1/2</sup>*x**a**x**a*<sup>1/2</sup> = (*a*<sup>1/2</sup>*x**a*<sup>1/2</sup>)<sup>2</sup>, which implies that *a*<sup>1/2</sup>*x**a*<sup>1/2</sup> = (*a*<sup>1/2</sup>*b**a*<sup>1/2</sup>)<sup>1/2</sup>.  Since *a* is invertible, *x* must be *a*<sup>−1/2</sup>(*a*<sup>1/2</sup>*b**a*<sup>1/2</sup>)<sup>1/2</sup>*a*<sup>−1/2</sup>.

**Existence:** It is easy to check that 
$x=\sqrt{a}^{-1}\sqrt{\sqrt{a}\hspace{.15cm}b\sqrt{a}\quad}\sqrt{a}^{-1}$
 satisfies the condition.

I do not think that anything in this argument depends on the fact that we are considering matrices, but let me avoid claiming things about the subject which I do not know well.

Comment: This does work for arbitrary C* algebras.

Comment: Thank you. You proof works perfectly well in the context of a general C*-algebra.

Comment: @Jonas, @André: Thank you for the comment about general C*-algebra!

Comment: Quick comment: in the matrix case, this is known as the *matrix geometric mean* $x=GM(A^{-1},B)$ of $A^{-1}$ and $B$; it has an interesting interpretation in terms of Riemannian geometry, and it is a nontrivial problem to generalize it to a "mean" of more than two matrices satisfying some basic properties. References: Bhatia, Holbrook *Riemannian Geometry and Geometric Means*, LAA '06, and *Noncommutative geometric means*, Math. Intelligencer, for a less technical exposition. Where does this problem arise for $\mathbb{C}^*$ algebras? I'm interested!

Comment: The proof uses that $\sqrt{a} b \sqrt{a} = (\sqrt{b} \sqrt{b})^{*} (\sqrt{b} \sqrt{a})$, which is therefore positive and has a root.

Comment: @Federico: I was trying to prove existence and uniqueness of normalized solutions for the "conjugate equations", by using the conclusion of [Lemma 3.9 in Longo's paper *A Theory of Dimension* http://arxiv.org/pdf/funct-an/9604008] as my working definition for the meaning of "normalized".

Comment: @André: thanks for the reference -- unfortunately, I am afraid I lack too much background to understand it... in any case, if you need some more properties of your function $x=f(a^{-1},b)$, there's several papers on them (in the matrix case) and I believe that most properties carry over to $C^*$ algebras.

Comment: Going beyond Federico's comment, $x$ is the maximal element among those for which the block matrix $\begin{pmatrix} b & x \\\\ x & a^{-1} \end{pmatrix}$ is non-negative.

Comment: Is $x$ unique in case of matrices upto some equivalence?

Answer (score 0):

In the case of $\Bbb{M}_n(\Bbb{C})$, you should diagonalize $a$, say $d(\lambda_1,\cdots,\lambda_n)$. Then $a^{1/2}$ is $d(\sqrt{\lambda_1},\cdots,\sqrt{\lambda_n})$. Easily you can find $a^{-1/2}$ (since $a^{1/2}$ is of course invertible). The rest is just following the previous answer:

$x=a^{-1/2}(a^{1/2}ba^{1/2})^{1/2}a^{-1/2}.$

Then you can return the basis to the previous one (i.e. the basis before diagonalization of $a$).

Comment: Well this just provides a computation of $\sqrt{a}$ in the case of matrix algebras. Else this is just a copy of the accepted answer.

Comment: @ Martin: In the last part of the question Andre says:"Already in the case $A=M 2 (\Bbb{C})$ , I don't know how to solve this." This is the answer: " using unitary matrices switch the basis to one appropriate one and the follow the previous answer, then using the inverse of that unitary matrix return the base: The $x$."
So I used the accepted answer in Matrix Analysis to find $x$! Nothing more! 